# How can I set the backgroundColor of a WKInterfaceController programmatically?

Tags: watchkit

I couldn't find any way of changing the overall background color of the Watch app interface programmatically.

I therefore tried creating a fullscreen WKInterfaceGroup and changing the backgroundColor of that.

```
    centralGroup.setBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0))
```

However, I still have unfilled rounded corners and lines on borders.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve my goal, of an edge-to-edge background color that fills the screen?

Comment: apple devforum said it can't be done yet. However I've created a request for it on bugreport.apple.com

Comment: The default background is black, not purple, correct? Or perhaps this has been resolved in beta 3?

Comment: It's black. I changed it in the storyboard. But I can't do it in runtime

Comment: Can you clarify how you changed this edge colour to purple/blue right to the edge in the storyboard? Was this through using a background image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While you can set a background color for a WKInterfaceController in the storyboard, there is no API that lets you programmatically set it in the present Xcode 6.2 beta 3.

However, you can create a full screen WKInterfaceGroup and set the color of that programmatically. If you also `setCornerRadius:` to 0 you get the following result:
[image: Apple watch screen with screen filled with green]
Clearly, there are still black lines at the edges here. The other possibility was that setting a solid color image as the background might perhaps scale to fill the full screen with one of the scaling options, but I tested this and the result is identical to the above.

However, it is important to consider the hardware this will be running on. Apple have said more than once in their public statements about the Watch that the intersection between the laminated screen and the edges is so seamless that you essentially can't tell where the screen ends and the edges begin. Taking this at face value, as long as you set the background color of the WKInterfaceController to clear or black in interface builder, so that these edges are black to match the screen surround, then these black lines should be invisible to the end user and are something you can safely ignore.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I done it:

1. Add `WKInterfaceGroup` and `setCornerRadius` to 0
2. Go to `WKInterfaceController` Attribute Inspector and change Left/Right insets to 0 (Fig.1) (This will remove the extra black line on the left & right side)
3. Change the color of the WKInterfaceGroup to whatever you want :)

**Fig.1**

[image: Attribute Inspector]

Answer (score 3):

Change insets of Your WKInterfaceController to custom and set all to 0. Also, change corner radius of group to 0 too. Enjoy.

Comment: aumanets answer is more thorough so I +1 his and -1 yours to help them sort better.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the corner radius of the `WKInterfaceGroup` to 0.  You can use `setCornerRadius:` to change the corner radius.

Comment: still interface has those side lines on the left and right

Comment: I have not been able to put a group over the far left and right edges.

Comment: Do not forget to set edge insets of controller to 0. By default it has 1 at left and right.

Comment: those side lines won't be visible on the actual watch, of course